# OpenCV - HSV range of values for tracking red color

Tags: c++, video, opencv, hue

Could you please tell me how to what are ranges for Hue, Saturation and Value indices for intense red?

I try to use this values for color tracking and I couldn't find a specific answer via Google.

Comment: Well, the Hue would be red, so either 0 or 360 on the hue wheel, intense means saturation is has the maximum value (100 generally, but depends on implementation) and the brightness would also have the maximum value. HTH

Comment: opencv HSV ranges are H: 0-180, S: 0-255, V: 0-255

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are the only one who can answer this question, since we don't know your criteria for "intense red". Collect as many samples as you can, some of which you consider intense red and some which are close but just miss the cut. Convert them all to HSL. Study the pattern.

You might put together a small app that has sliders for the H, S, and L parameters and displays a block of color corresponding to the settings. That will tell you your limits very quickly.

Answer (score 5):

you can map any color to OpenCV HSV. Actually opencv use 180<sup>0</sup> hue cylinder while ideally it is 360, on the orher hand MS paint use 240<sup>0</sup> cyllinder.
So to get OpenCV HSV value, simply open MS paint, open mixer, and read the value of HSV, now to map this value into OpenCV HSV multiply it with 180/240.
the range to value for saturation and value is 0<sup>0</sup>-180<sup>0</sup>